# Find exact word between two HTML tags

Tags: regex, tags

I need to find, if it is possible, the right regexp (Perl syntax, since I'm using Sublime Text) to find the string ' and ' inside two span tags.
The line look like this one:

```
<span class="CEURAUTHORS">Xing Xu, Atsushi Shimada and Rin-Ichiro Taniguchi</span>
```

I've tried

```
(?<=CEURAUTHORS">)\sand\s(?=.*</span>)
```

but it's not what I want.
Any idea?

Comment: What is _to find ' and '_

Comment: Which regex? PCRE will let you do this: http://regex101.com/r/sS0qS6/1 but others may not be so friendly. Is it Python, Javascript, Ruby, ...?

Comment: Per @RahilWazir's comment, please show what output you get with what you have tried and what output you would like to see instead.

Comment: The @OnlineCop solution works right for me: I didn't know the use of `\K`:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no nesting of tags, here are three options depending on your regex flavor.

**Option 1: Capture Group (works everywhere)**

```
<span[^>]*>(?:(?!</span).)*( and )[^<>]*</span>
```

The match is in Group 1

**Option 2: `\K` in Perl, PCRE (PHP, R...), Ruby 2+**

```
<span[^>]*>(?:(?!</span).)*\K and (?=[^<>]*</span>)
```

**Option 3: Infinite Lookbehind (.NET, `regex` module for Python)**

```
(?<=<span[^>]*>(?:(?!</span).)*) and (?=[^<>]*</span>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
<span.*?>.*(\band\b).*<\/span>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/yZ7jX6/2)**

[image]

Comment: That's close but not quite right (you can see the problem [in this demo](http://regex101.com/r/yZ7jX6/4))

Comment: Hey @zx81 how're you doing? I saw your point actually I think we should ask that to OP, maybe he wants that too but thanks to point that.